# Region Boundary in Scatter Chart in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I need to Set Region Boundary in the Scatter Chart Something like this

[image]

I used plot bands for x and Y Axis but it is Something like this

[image]

How to achieve the Region Boundary in highhcharts

Here is my fiddle

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/gsc1grmd/][3]
```

where the scatter points is between xAxis 50 - 120 and yAxis 0 - 100 but i need boundaries around the scatter plots

Comment: You will get more help if you post a jsfiddle showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/gsc1grmd/ where the scatter points is between xAxis 50 - 120 and yAxis 0 - 100 but i need boundaries only between these axis like a square or like graph which i show in above image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this:

1. Use the renderer directly to draw the box
2. Use another series to draw the box

The second series option is probably the easiest, e.g.

```
  ,{
         name: 'bounds',
         color: 'red',
        type:'line'
        data: [[50,10],[50,100],[120,100],[120,10],[50,10]]

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74usy0ws/

You can style the line and corner points the the same way as you style any line series. If you want the cross hairs across the box, you can just add extra points to the series.

Comment: the same thing i thought but is there any other way